# How to export part of a huge Canvas to PNG

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to export a Canvas to multiple PNG files. Trying to export the whole canvas to an image and then crop the image failed due to the size of the resulting image (something like 20.000px x 5.000px).

Now the strategy is to split the main canvas into smaller parts and then export each individual part to an image. The resulting image though, doesn't show the image from the main canvas below it.

Any ideas? Here is the code used to test the splitting of the Canvas (the real one is much larger than 1024x1024):

```
public void TestPrintPartOfCanvas()
{
    //the main canvas
    var main = new Canvas();
    main.Width = 1024;
    main.Height = 1024;
    main.Background = Brushes.Blue;

    //place something inside the canvas
    var redRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
    redRect.Fill = Brushes.OrangeRed;
    redRect.Width = 128;
    redRect.Height = 128;

    main.Children.Add(redRect);

    // reset current transform (in case it is scaled or rotated)
    var transform = main.LayoutTransform;
    main.LayoutTransform = null;

    // Get the size of canvas
    var size = new Size(main.Width, main.Height);

    //representing the first part of the main canvas
    var part = new Canvas();
    part.Width = 256;
    part.Height = 256;
    part.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

    main.Children.Add(part);

    // Measure and arrange the surface
    main.Measure(size);
    main.Arrange(new Rect(size));

    // Create a render bitmap and push the part to it
    var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)part.Width, (int)part.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderBitmap.Render(part);

    // Create a file stream for saving image
    using (var outStream = new FileStream("p:/part.png", FileMode.Create))
    {
        // Use png encoder for our data
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        // push the rendered bitmap to it
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
        // save the data to the stream
        encoder.Save(outStream);
    }

    // Restore previously saved layout
    main.LayoutTransform = transform;
}
```

Comment: Is it the `main` Canvas (sized 1024x1024) that you finally want to render? It shouldn't be a problem to do that in one go. The `part` Canvas is of course empty. You haven't added any Children.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that better. The 1024x1024 is only to test the ability to divide it into smaller parts. The main Canvas in a real environment is usually much larger than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may easily crop a part of the Canvas by adjusting the Arrange rectangle:

```
var size = new Size(main.Width, main.Height);
main.Measure(size);

var cropOffset = new Point(-256, -256);
main.Arrange(new Rect(cropOffset, size));

var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(256, 256, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderBitmap.Render(main);
```

The above crops a 256x256 rectangle at position 256,256.